# How to center a class button

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend

Hi I was trying to center the sign up button but nothing happens when i use text-align or align center how can i do it ? the reference code that i use it has no code lines has align command this is the cheatsheet code for me what is the diffrence ?
note: i did find some commands like left%50 in other threads but it just make worst (only centered one signup button and other ones has gone)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flexbox Pricing Table</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
    }

    .pricing-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      gap: 2rem;
    }

    .pricing-plan {
      flex: 1;
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .plan-title {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .plan-price {
      font-size: 48px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .plan-features {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .plan-features li {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .plan-button {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #ff6600;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1250px) {
      .pricing-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Basic</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$11.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 10GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 1 User</li>
        <li> Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 50GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 5 Users</li>
        <li>✅ Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 100GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 10 Users</li>
        <li>✅ 24/7 Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your button tag needs to have a closing button tag. Right now, it is:

`<button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a>`

but it should be:

```
<button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
```

2. To make it center, one way to accomplish this is to make the button a block level element and then use auto margin like this:

   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;

Here is a working rendition of your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Flexbox Pricing Table</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
      }

      .pricing-container {
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        gap: 2rem;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px
      }

      .pricing-plan {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }

      /* Hint: What can you do with a media query and flexbox? */
      @media (max-width: 1250px) {}

      .plan-title {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .plan-price {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 48px;
      }

      .plan-button {
        background-color: #ff6600;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
                display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .plan-features li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="pricing-container">
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Basic</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$9.99/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li>✅ 10GB Storage</li>
          <li>✅ 1 User</li>
          <li> Support</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li>✅ 50GB Storage</li>
          <li>✅ 5 Users</li>
          <li>✅ Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li>✅ 100GB Storage</li>
          <li>✅ 10 Users</li>
          <li>✅ 24/7 Support</li>
        </ul>
                
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: do i have to convert make a block element every single time for buttons ?

Comment: with this method, yes, you would have to apply those properties to each button in order to have them centered.

Comment: if you did not want the button to be a block element, you could set it as inline margin like so:

margin-inline: 50%;
inline-size: max-content;

Answer (score 0):

just add a `display: flex; and flex-direction: column;` to the pricing-plan

and add `align-self: center;` to the button

> Note: don't forget to change the closing tag of button to </button>
> instead of </a>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flexbox Pricing Table</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .pricing-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      gap: 2rem;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 50px
    }
    
    .pricing-plan {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    /* Hint: What can you do with a media query and flexbox? */
    
    @media (max-width: 1250px) {}
    
    .plan-title {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .plan-price {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    
    .plan-button {
      background-color: #ff6600;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      align-self: center
    }
    
    .plan-features li {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Basic</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$9.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 10GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 1 User</li>
        <li> Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 50GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 5 Users</li>
        <li>✅ Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 100GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 10 Users</li>
        <li>✅ 24/7 Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```